# How use context bounds with type constraints in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, type-constraints

I have a function Bar

```
def Bar[F :TypeTag ](fList: List[String]): (F) = {
typeOf[F] match {
  case t if t =:= typeOf[FooA] => returnsomething.asInstanceOf[F]
  case t if t =:= typeOf[FooB] => returnanother.asInstanceOf[F]
}
}
```

Then i want use type constraints those Bar take only Foo-child types.
but i cant use this contstruction

```
def getFilter[F <:Foo:TypeTag ](fList: List[String]): (F) = {
typeOf[F] match {
  case t if t =:= typeOf[OpsosFilter] => OpsosFilter(loadFilter[String](fList)).asInstanceOf[F]
  case t if t =:= typeOf[OrganizationFilter] => OrganizationFilter(loadFilter[Long](fList)).asInstanceOf[F]
}
```

How i can resolve my problem?

Comment: ok,maybe need more really example. i have abstract class gwFilter and two child opsosFilter and orgfilter. if i tried do  `def getFilter[F<:gwFilter: TypeTag](fList: List[String]): (F)`
i get error `Error:(10, 20) class gwFilter takes type parameters
  def getFilter[F<:gwFilter: TypeTag](fList: List[String]): (F) = {
                   ^`

Comment: Why don't you create two methods ? One that returns `OpsosFilter` and the other an `OrganizationFilter` ?

Comment: That compiler error is telling you that the class `gwFilter` takes type parameters. You can't have `F <: gwFilter` if `gwFilter` is a parameterized type. Maybe `F <: gwFilter[_]` is what you want.